# Get SubClass Instance

Tags: php, class, inheritance, instance

How can I check the subclass that is calling a method to determine how this method is going to be executed?

On Classes.php:

```
class Generic {

public function foo() {

// if its being called by Specific_1 subclass
echo "bar";

// if its being called by Specific_2 subclass
echo "zoo";
  }
}

class Specific_1 extends Generic {}

class Specific_2 extends Generic {}
```

On script:

```
$spec1 = new Specific_1();
$spec2 = new Specific_2();

spec1->foo() // pretend to echo bar
spec2->foo() // pretend to echo zoo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php) keyword:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

class Generic {
    public function foo() {
        if($this instanceof Specific_1)echo "bar";
        if($this instanceof Specific_2)echo "zoo";
    }
}

class Specific_1 extends Generic {}
class Specific_2 extends Generic {}

$a = new Specific_1();
$a->foo();

echo PHP_EOL;

$b = new Specific_2();
$b->foo();
?>
```

Shows:

```
bar
zoo
```

---

Try [`is_a()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) function:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

class Generic {
    public function foo() {
        if(is_a($this, 'Specific_1'))echo "bar";
        if(is_a($this, 'Specific_2'))echo "baz";
    }
}

class Specific_1 extends Generic {}
class Specific_2 extends Generic {}

$a = new Specific_1();
$a->foo();

echo PHP_EOL;

$b = new Specific_2();
$b->foo();
?>
```

Shows:

```
bar
baz
```

---

Another way with [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

class Generic {
    public function foo() {
        switch($class = get_called_class()){
        case 'Specific_1':
            echo "bar";
            break;

        case 'Specific_2':
            echo "zoo";
            break;

        default:
            // default behaviour...
        }
    }
}

class Specific_1 extends Generic {}
class Specific_2 extends Generic {}

$a = new Specific_1();
$a->foo();

echo PHP_EOL;

$b = new Specific_2();
$b->foo();
?>
```

Shows:

```
bar
zoo
```

**P.S.:** Why don't you just override method within each class?